# How can they catch me, how can i hide my self

Tags: proxy, ip-spoofing, user-tracking

Im using a website and somehow they can find out that i am using a proxy.

My first question is how can they do. How can they find out this? And Second what can i do i mean how can i hide my self, is there any way that i use proxy and they can not catch me?

what i think is they have some famous proxies's ip or whatever and i am using one of them, am i right?

Thanks

Comment: Look into the TOR Project/TOR Browser Bundle, https://www.torproject.org/projects/torbrowser.html.en

Comment: @raz depending on who "they" are, this might not be viable due to compromised exit nodes, etc.

Comment: A compromised exit node does not identify original source.  It only knows the previous node and the end destination.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

They can realize you are from a proxy if enough distinct traffic is coming from the end point of the proxy or if it is a published proxy end point.  That doesn't mean they can tell who you are, but there are some large caveats.

If "they" is a government agency with jurisdictional control over the proxy or the proxy isn't an encrypted VPN proxy or isn't used enough, then it is possible that a connection could be tracked back to it's originator by looking at which IPs were talking to the proxy or by forcing the proxy to cooperate.

Additionally, if you do anything while using the proxy that might identify you (such as logging in to a website) then your anonymity goes out the window as well.

So in short, it is pretty easy to tell if your connection is coming from a proxy or anonymous connection as anonymity requires volume and volume coming from an IP can be detected and the IP can be marked as a possible anonymous proxy in databases used for proxy detection, but it doesn't implicitly mean that using it is insecure, because there still likely isn't a direct link back to you to the non-governmental or telecom observer.